# Error when starting Windows Service: Connection "actively refused"

Tags: asp.net, connection, windows-service, socket

I have used .NET to create a service installation package (msi) that, when run, installs a Windows service designed to run an instance of Apache Solr (to aid in searching from a web application). I am running the service on the same machine where Solr is hosted. When I start it up, I get:

> Service cannot be started. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException:
>   No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it [MachineIP]:8983 at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endpoingSnapshot,
>   SocketAddress socketAddress) at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout,
>   Exception& exception)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at
>   SOLRService.SolrService.OnStart(String[] args) at
>   System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object
>   state)

Where [MachineIP] is the IP of the box. Again, I'm attempting to start this service from the same box it's trying to connect to. I tried pinging its own IP, just for kicks, and it came back fine. I'm just not understanding why a server would actively refuse a connection to itself. We've been able to get this to work in development.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the windows firewall to make sure port 8983 is open in the proper context?

Answer (score 1):

`Connection refused` means that nothing is listening on that port (8983 in your case). Start the service which is supposed to listen for connections on that port.